# dynamically filter rows of a HTML table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I have this table:

```
<table border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Broj_pu</td>
        <td>Naziv_pu</td>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Naselje</td>
        <td>zupanija</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" ID="broj_pu" onkeydown="Filter(document.getElementById('broj_pu').value,     'broj_pu')" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" ID="naziv_pu" onkeydown="Filter(document.getElementById('naziv_pu').value,   'naziv_pu')" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" ID="ID" onkeydown="Filter(document.getElementById('ID').value,           'ID')" /></td>  
        <td><input type="text" ID="naselje" onkeydown="Filter(document.getElementById('naselje').value,     'naselje')" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" ID="zupanija" onkeydown="Filter(document.getElementById('zupanija').value,   'zupanija')" /></td>    
    </tr>

    <tr class="row" ID="row_filter">
        <td>10000</td>
        <td>Zagreb</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Sljeme</td>
        <td>ZAGREBACKA</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row" ID="row_filter">
        <td>10000</td>
        <td>Zagreb</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Zagreb-dio</td>
        <td>ZAGREBACKA</td>
    </tr>
<!-- A lot of rows -->
...
</table>
```

And also I have started this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Filter(text, column_name){
        var x = document.getElementByClassName("row");
        var i = 0;
        var y;

        if (text != ""){
            switch (column_name){
                case "broj_pu":
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
                    y = x[i].getElementByTagName("td");
                    if((y[0].value).match(text) == null){
                        x[i].attributes(style) = "{display:none;}";
                    }
                }
                break;

                case "naziv_pu":
                    y = x[i].getElementByTagName("td");
                    if((y[1].value).match(text) == null){
                        x[i].attributes(style) = "{display:none;}";
                    }
                }
                break;

                case "ID":
                    y = x[i].getElementByTagName("td");
                    if((y[2].value).match(text) == null){
                        x[i].attributes(style) = "{display:none;}";
                    }
                }
                break;

                case "naselje":
                    y = x[i].getElementByTagName("td");
                    if((y[3].value).match(text) == null){
                        x[i].attributes(style) = "{display:none;}";
                    }
                }
                break;

                case "zupanija":
                    y = x[i].getElementByTagName("td");
                    if((y[4].value).match(text) == null){
                        x[i].attributes(style) = "{display:none;}";
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now, I need to filter the table as the user inputs letters to the text fields, but I have no idea how to edit the display document as I enter the data.

Anyone have an idea?

EDIT1:

So I edited the script but it doesn't seem to work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can an answer include jQuery?

Comment: You should not have multiple HTML elements with the same IDs.  The element's ID is supposed to be unique.

Comment: Don't edit the document, edit the styling of the document. So select the elements that don't match and add `display:none;` to their rows' style attribute.

Comment: i am totally unfamiliar with jQuery, so i would prefer an answer without it.
As far as the ID goes, i dont know how to get the elements i want in any other way, if you know one please do tell :)

Comment: Also, you might have better luck using the `onkeyup` attribute. Or JQuery, for that matter.

Comment: To get elements by their class name use:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: ok, will switch it to go with search for class name and try the `dispaly:none` thing, ill post back

Comment: seriously think about using jQuery. it would turn your spaghetti into like 8 lines of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is reminding me of how java script is nasty without any framework support :)

However I have sorted-out this issue for you ( tested on firefox 10.0.2).

check the complete working solution on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7RKk/)

please remember this is just working example , you might need to write ALL-Browser compliant script .

**script:**

```
var filters=['hide_broj_pu','hide_naziv_pu','hide_ID','hide_naselje','hide_zupanija'];

function ExcludeRows(cls){

  var skipRows=[];

  for(i=0;i<filters.length;i++)
      if(filters[i]!=cls) skipRows.push(filters[i]);

  var pattern=skipRows.join('|')

  return pattern;
}

function Filter(srcField){

   var node=srcField.parentNode;

   var index=srcField.parentNode.cellIndex;
    //all the DATA rows

   var dataRows= document.getElementsByClassName("row");

   //ensure that dataRows do not have any filter class added already
   var kids= dataRows.length;

   var filter ='hide_'+srcField.id;

   var pattern = ExcludeRows(filter);

   var skipRow = new RegExp(pattern,"gi");

   var searchReg =new RegExp('^'+srcField.value,'gi');

   var replaceCls= new RegExp(filter,'gi');

   for(i=0; i< kids ; i++){
       //skip if already filter applied  

       if(dataRows[i].className.match(skipRow)) continue;

       //now we know which column to search
       //remove current filter
       dataRows[i].className=dataRows[i].className.replace(replaceCls,'');

       if(!dataRows[i].cells[index].innerHTML.trim().match(searchReg))
          dataRows[i].className=dataRows[i].className +' '+ filter;

    }



}
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr><td>Broj_pu</td><td>Naziv_pu</td><td>ID</td><td>Naselje</td><td>zupanija</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" ID="broj_pu"    onkeydown="Filter(this)" /></td>
<td><input type="text" ID="naziv_pu"   onkeydown="Filter(this)" /></td>
<td><input type="text" ID="ID"         onkeydown="Filter(this)" /></td>  
<td><input type="text" ID="naselje"    onkeydown="Filter(this)" /></td>
<td><input type="text" ID="zupanija"   onkeydown="Filter(this)" /></td>   
</tr>

<tr class="row" ><td>10000</td><td>Zagreb</td><td>1</td><td>Sljeme</td><td>ZAGREBACKA</td></tr>
<tr class="row" ><td>10000</td><td>Zagreb</td><td>2</td><td>Zagreb-dio</td><td>ZAGREBACKA</td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide_broj_pu,
.hide_naziv_pu,
.hide_ID,
.hide_naselje,
.hide_zupanija
{display:none}
```

Comment: btw, do you have a good framework to suggest for JS, HTMP, PHP and CSS? just started so im down to notepad++ and xampp for the server side stuff, but i could use  a good framework.

Comment: All in one choose Yii , which has JQuery support

Comment: That works. But it is possible that it can work on href fields ? <td class="R0C1"><s:property value="prs"/> 
<a href="<s:url value='https://ur;/web/default/%{prs}'/>#scope_tab" target="_blank"></a>

Comment: @Ammad use jquery tablesorter plugin with https://github.com/jbritten/jquery-tablesorter-filter or http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/17/

Answer (score 1):

For Javascript Table Search, Try:

```
<p>Search: <input type="text" id="searchTerm" onkeyup="doSearch()" /></p>

<table id="dataTable">

<script>
function doSearch() {
            var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
            input = document.getElementById("searchTerm");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
                for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
                    if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (found) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                    found = false;
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```