# Dynamically filtering rows of HTML table having <href > link elements as column data

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using HTML and Java script and below mention solution is working fine for many of the columns that i am using.

[dynamically filter rows of a HTML table using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092765/dynamically-filter-rows-of-a-html-table-using-javascript)

```
var filters=['hide_broj_pu','hide_naziv_pu','hide_ID','hide_naselje','hide_zupanija'];

function ExcludeRows(cls){

  var skipRows=[];

  for(i=0;i<filters.length;i++)
      if(filters[i]!=cls) skipRows.push(filters[i]);

  var pattern=skipRows.join('|')

  return pattern;
}

function Filter(srcField){

   var node=srcField.parentNode;

   var index=srcField.parentNode.cellIndex;
    //all the DATA rows

   var dataRows= document.getElementsByClassName("row");

   //ensure that dataRows do not have any filter class added already
   var kids= dataRows.length;

   var filter ='hide_'+srcField.id;

   var pattern = ExcludeRows(filter);

   var skipRow = new RegExp(pattern,"gi");

   var searchReg =new RegExp('^'+srcField.value,'gi');

   var replaceCls= new RegExp(filter,'gi');

   for(i=0; i< kids ; i++){
       //skip if already filter applied  

       if(dataRows[i].className.match(skipRow)) continue;

       //now we know which column to search
       //remove current filter
       dataRows[i].className=dataRows[i].className.replace(replaceCls,'');

       if(!dataRows[i].cells[index].innerHTML.trim().match(searchReg))
          dataRows[i].className=dataRows[i].className +' '+ filter;

    }



}
```

It filters well for  like this, 
`<td class="R0C1"><s:property value="owner" /></td>`

However, Above solution won't work if my columns have values that are Href links as shown below. For example:

```
  <td class="R0C1"><s:property value="prs"/>    
    <a href="<s:url value='https://url.net/web/default/%{prs}'/>#scope_tab" target="_blank"></a> </td>
```

What what changes i need to do with Java Script filter function that can also work equally well for  link elements.

Comment: That code filters by the start of an entry. To work for href, remove the `'^'+`.

Comment: Hi aaron, Thanks for the fix. Please post in answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code filters by the start of an entry.

To **work** for href, remove the `'^'+`.

To **match only** in href (to avoid false positives, e.g. `href`, `target`, `blank`) do this:

```
// var searchReg = new RegExp(srcField.value, 'gi');

var aTag = dataRows[i].cells[index].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
var href = aTag ? aTag.getAttribute("href") : '';
if (!href.match(searchReg))
    dataRows[i].className = dataRows[i].className + ' ' + filter;
```